# Magnetoresistance and Ionic conduction in mixed conductors

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I've been facing a question recently on ionic conduction and have not had much luck coming across resources to reference (if there are some please point me in their direction!)

In a mixed conductor there is some ionic conductivity and some electron conductivity. We can expect both of these charge carriers to be in flow simultaneously and homogeneously throughout the material (?). If this mixed conductor also happens to have magnetic properties; specifically if it exhibits Magnetoresistance such as in the mixed conductor SrFeO3 then how does this variable resistance affect ion conduction? Does it differ from the normal effects of resistance on electron conduction? Thanks in advance!